# problem with accessing getElementById using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and i don't know why it doesn't function

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function StopBackgroundMusic()
{
var MusicObj = document.getElementById("BackgroundMusic");

MusicObj.data = "http://www.oreillynet.com/examples/oreilly/digitalmedia/2005/02/ableton_intro_0205_gtr.mp3";
MusicObj.autoplay = "false";
MusicObj.autostart = "false";


return MusicObj;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<OBJECT ID="BackgroundMusic" data="http://www.oreillynet.com/examples/oreilly/digitalmedia/2005/02/ableton_intro_0205_gtr.mp3" TYPE="audio/mpeg" height="0" width="0">
<PARAM NAME="autostart" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="true">

</OBJECT>

<form> 


<input type='button' onclick='StopBackgroundMusic()' value='Stop music'/>

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help enormously if you would be more specific about the problem than to just say that this "doesn't function."

Comment: Why do you think that adding the `autoplay` and `autostart` properties to the OBJECT element should have any effect?

Comment: Why would switching the autostart or the autoplay to false stop the current playing of the music?

Comment: I try to stop the song but it has not any effect

Answer (score 3):

Try setting data to `null` instead of setting the music URL again.

Another alternative is removing the object node when you press the stop button:

```
function StopBackgroundMusic()
{
    var MusicObj = document.getElementById("BackgroundMusic");
    MusicObj.parentNode.removeChild(MusicObj);
}
```

Comment: @joni: Then try removing the whole object. I never used the object tag for playing audio but I'm 95% sure there is no JavaScript interface to control the audio. Or it may depend on the plugin which plays the audio. If you want real control over the audio you might try the HTML 5 audio tag. But it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: function StopBackgroundMusic()
{
    var MusicObj = document.getElementById("BackgroundMusic");
    MusicObj.parentNode.removeChild(MusicObj);
}
It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

does the element "BackgroundMusic" is encapsulated within a form element? if so try similar things like this one,

```
document.getElementById("[formID].BackgroundMusic");
```

if you use a form tag, give it an id,

```
<form id="music">
```